# Can I access types created in F# Interactive with System.CodeDom?

Tags: f#, razor

I am creating my type in FSX and passing those types into the Razor templating engine with the open source [RazorEngine project](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/).

Hosting Razor outside of ASP.NET requires compiling the Razor templates.  If I pass a model created in FSX into the template, will System.CodeDom be able to have access to that type created by FSI?  The basic error that I get is "The type or namespace name 'FSI_0004' could not be found".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code that's compiled using `System.CodeDom` cannot generally have access to the code loaded in F# Interactive - the CodeDom essentially writes the C#/F# source code to disk and then invokes the command line compiler on the code (and the command line compiler cannot reference code loaded in F# Interactive).

There may be a way to get it working though - You could use the F# CodeDom provider from [PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com). You could modify it to generate the source code (as it currently does) and then send the generated code to F# Interactive (instead of invoking command line compiler). This way, the code compiled on-the-fly could see F# Interactive code.

There are some issues that need to be resolved

- Is it possible to provide your own CodeDom provider to RazorEngine?
- The F# CodeDom provider may not correctly handle code generated by Razor (so you may need to fix/workaround a few things in the F# CodeDom provider). You may also need to modify it to generate code that works nicely with F# interactive (e.g. remove top-level namespaces)
- What instance of F# Interactive do you want to use? (And how to get standard input, so that you can send your code there)
- Do you need to load the compiled assembly and pass it back to Razor? I'm not sure if this can be done with F# Interactive.

These all depend on your scenario - but I guess that it may be possible to get what you want (possibly with some workarounds).

Comment: Thanks Tomas.  I'll look into F# CodeDom.  I'm not 100% sure but I believe that Razor needs to load the assembly, so FSI is most likely a bad match.  The simplest solution is to turn this into a command line tool.

Comment: An alternative workaround is to annotate the razor template with @model dynamic at the top.  This causes the template to be use the f# type through a 'dynamic' reference and avoids the compile time dependency on the f# type.